# Rails Engine cannot find templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-engines

I am trying to make a Rails controller spec work in my Engine. The controller test looks like this:

```
module Notes
  describe NotesController do
    routes { Notes::Engine.routes }

    it 'renders index' do
      get 'index'
    end
  end
end
```

Currently I am using a dummy generated with the [Combustion gem](https://github.com/pat/combustion) so my dummy configuration routes are:

```
# spec/internal/config/routes.rb
require 'notes'
require Notes::Engine.root.join('config/routes')

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Notes::Engine => '/', as: 'notes'
  # mount Notes::Engine => '/notes'
end
```

**PROBLEM 1:**

I am trying to avoid a copy-paste of Engine routes into the dummy config file by mounting the engine. However I cannot find the right configuration to make the `routes { Notes::Engine.routes }` line redundant on my specs.

**PROBLEM 2:**

The controller spec fails when trying to find the `app/views` folder on my Rails dummy `./spec/internal`. So far I fixed the problem by making a symbolic link from `spec/internal/app` to my real `./app`.

Is there is a more clean way to find my views?. I expected the Rails dummy to pull directly the app folders from the Engine but it is not happening without the link.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem (PROBLEM 2). And it was because I had slim templates and not gem 'slim-rails' in gemfile and also for Rails 5 you need gem 'rails-controller-testing'

so try adding

```
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'rails-controller-testing'
```

run 'bundle'

Answer (score 0):

For engines, the tests go in the spec directory inside the engine and you test it as a completely separate application, independent of your regular rails app.  From there it will have access to the routes that are defined in its config file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your gem may not have a subclass of `Rails::Engine`, and thus won't automatically locate Rails standard directories within the gem. In your case, you'll want a class called `Notes::Engine`, which would usually live at `lib/notes/engine.rb`, and is a subclass of `Rails::Engine`. As part of the loading of your gem, you'll also want to load that file.

You can see an example of this in the Gutentag gem - the subclass:
https://github.com/pat/gutentag/blob/master/lib/gutentag/engine.rb

And the require:
https://github.com/pat/gutentag/blob/master/lib/gutentag.rb#L23

(Gutencag uses Combustion for testing, albeit not with routes, but it may be a helpful reference generally.)

Comment: Thanks @pat ! I do have the `Rails::Engine` subclass. Otherwise the line `Notes::Engine.routes` would not work. The combustion readme mentions the `routes.rb` file but I use the method above to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I think might very well live with just a symlink of `config/routes.rb` file and the `app` folder from the generated dummy to my engine. It works but it is such a dirty hack I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: BTW. The symlink approach was my way to solve the two issues mentioned here: https://github.com/pat/combustion#using-actioncontroller-and-actionview

Comment: I've not needed a symlink before... certainly feels hackish to me :|

Comment: Can you add your spec_helper.rb file to the question?

Comment: My case is slightly more complex than `pat/gutentag` because I am doing a app/controller test that requires an app/views. It feels strange that I must symlink the `app` folder to make things work thou. I will take some time tomorrow to build a very basic Rails engines skeleton and review that way my knowledge of engines.